# How to handle type generics for variables in Java methods?

Tags: java, generics, methods

I'm something of a newbie with Java and I'm trying to learn how to use generics. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with this code?

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Generics {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer a = new Integer(28);

        Integer[] b = {2, 4, 8, 16, 20, 28, 34, 57, 98, 139}; 
            //I'd prefer int[], but understand native types don't go with generics

        int c = which(a, b); // <--- error here, see below

        System.out.println("int: "+ c);
    }

    static <T extends Number> int which( T a, Collection<T> b) {
        int match = -1;
        int j = 0;
        for (Iterator<T> itr = b.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            T t = (T) itr.next();
             if (a == t) {
                 match = j; 
                 break; 
             }
             j++;
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

**The Error:** `The method which(T, Collection<T>) in the type Generics is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, Integer[])`.

Granted, I could just use `int c = Arrays.binarySearch(b, a)` in this particular case (sorted, comparable elements) instead of the custom method `which`, but this is a learning exercise.

Can anyone explain what I'm misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array is not a Collection

try

```
static <T extends Number> int which( T a, T[] b) {
```

And, as Yanflea points, this change implies that (other optimizations added)

```
int j = 0;
for(T t : b) {
  if (a.equals(t)) {
    return j;
  }
  j++;
}
return -1;
```

Comment: You should precise that you have to fix the line 'for (Iterator<T> itr = b.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)' with this solution.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
Integer[] b = {2, 4, 8, 16, 20, 28, 34, 57, 98, 139}
```

by

```
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 8, 16, 20, 28, 34, 57, 98, 139);
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for (primarily changes to the method, not the caller), but educational, nonetheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace `which(a, b)` in your code with `which(a, Arrays.asList(b))`. `Arrays.asList` is a simply adapter that gets an array (of reference types) to conform to be viewed as a `List`; which allows you to use any method that is written for `List`s easily on an array (excluding arrays of primitives).